# How to delete object element from an array using JavaScript in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I want to Delete an element of items(Array) whose id matches with index in deleteItem(index).
Below is the code, I've tried so far:

```
  constructor(){
    super()        
    this.state = {
      items : [
        { id: 34523, type: 'a', data: 'aaa' },
        { id: 23452, type: 'b', data: 'bbb' }.
        { id: 45644, type: 'c', data: 'ccc' }
      ]
    }
  }

  deleteItem(index){
    const copyStateAr = Object.assign([], this.state.items)
    copyStateAr.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
      items: copyStateAr
    })  
  }
```

Note: Above code is working fine when I taking id as 1, 2, 3. But In case if I delete 2nd element first then the 3rd element doesn't getting deleted. 
Also, if possible suggest me other method or approach to do the same task ( it is kind of search (id) and delete element).

Comment: It's unclear if you are deleting by index or by id.  You've got 75% of your answers so far suggesting to do it by id.

Comment: Side note: Using `Object.assign` to copy an array is a bit non-idiomatic. The idiomatic ways are `this.state.items.slice()`, `[...this.state.items]`, and `Array.from(this.state.items)`. But `Object.assign` does work... :-)

Comment: make a copy of original but dont  sync original  comment this line' items: copyStateAr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet here is:

1. Don't delete by *index*, delete by *id*
2. Use the callback form of `setState` so you're dealing with up-to-date information

That's because state updates may be asynchronous and may be batched, so relying on the index can set you up for weird edge case failures.

So:

```
deleteItem(id) {
    this.setState(({items}) => ({items: items.filter(e => e.id !== id)}));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just delete objects by ID

```
deleteItem(id){
    this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.filter(x => x.id !== id)
    })  
  }
```

Comment: That's not what was asked.  They're asking to do it by index.

Comment: When updating state based on existing state (as here), it's important to use the callback version of `setState`, not the version you pass an object to. State updates may be asynchronous, and may be combined, so `this.state` may be out of date.

Comment: if you don with index you can check index and make sure index is  <=  number of element

Comment: @T.J.Crowder agree, my mistake. Will not update the answer since you have provided a one

Comment: @Wyck if you are so sure to give me a "-" then, please, get familiar with a similar answer to this question above from someone who is more authoritative...

Answer (score 0):

Index keeps changing . so if you have

```
{ id: 34523, type: 'a', data: 'aaa' },
        { id: 23452, type: 'b', data: 'bbb' }.
        { id: 45644, type: 'c', data: 'ccc' }
```

deleted 2 index

then structure becomes

```
{ id: 34523, type: 'a', data: 'aaa' },
      
        { id: 45644, type: 'c', data: 'ccc' }
```

so you better start deleting by id element. ADD a condition if index is <= number of element and send message index not found. You can make a copy of original and delete from copy.
So original will  always have full data.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the object with the specified id using .forEach higher order function, then change the state using setState;

```
const newArray = [];
this.state.items.forEach(object => {
    if ( object.id != specifiedId ) newArray.push(object);
});

this.setState({items: newArray});
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Just modify copystatear

```
const copyStateAr = Object.assign([], items).filter((value, i) => value.id !== id);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If possible explain what your code does, how is it different from the one on the question or why you did it this way. Code comments also works. For self explanatory code like this, it would be nice to explain why the code on question needed refactoring.